# Magento 2.4 shows 502 bad geteway error

Tags: magento2.4

I have installed magento 2.4.2  and installation is done but when tried to access through url it shows 502  bad gateway error

Comment: It is related to your web server configuration. It is hard to answer without knowing your server configuration. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

Comment: Is this an upgrade or new install? There could be some issues with an upgrade because they moved index.php into /pub folder. Check nginx.conf.sample and compare it with your nginx.conf for changes.

Comment: new installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

502 Bad Gateway its a webserver error, so something are going wrong here. We need to know about its NGINX or Apache webserver you are running you Magento on.

In my case I have created a Docker setup to have all the pre-config for me when I developer Magento code.

I know there are a huge NGINX config file you need to take care of if you are running on NGINX webserver, if you are running Apache I can't help here sorry.

The next step I see when you have running the upgrade cli command, you need to get the right access to your project folder in my case becures its local I run it, I just give it `chmod -R 777 project/` if you are running on production `777` its not recommended.

But again when you hit 502 Bad Gateway there can be a lot of different errors here on you webserver access log.

Remember Magento required (PHP, MySQL and Elastic) to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your document root to "pub" folder? From the newer version of Magento, you need to keep your document root to pub folder.